# Gradle: automatically choose GRADLE_HOME depending on the project

Tags: gradle

At my job we use gradle, so on my laptop I have a `~/.gradle/init.d` folder which contains the init scripts that define our enterprise-wide configuration, such as the URL of the local repository, docker publishing rules, checkstyle rules, etc.

I want to use gradle for a personal project, so I don't want to use any of these init scripts. Here are the ideas I have come up with so far:

1. Rename `~/.gradle` to `~/.gradle-work`, create `~/.gradle-personal`, and then symlink `~/.gradle` to `-work` or `-personal` depending on what I'm doing.
2. Have `~/.gradle` as my personal gradle settings, and create another gradle folder `~/dev/work/.gradle` with all my work init scripts. Make sure `$GRADLE_HOME` is set to `~/dev/work/.gradle` when running gradle for any work projects.
3. Some variant of 2 where gradle will automatically use `~/dev/work/.gradle` if it detects that the project is in the `~/dev/work/` folder.

Option 1 feels quite clumsy. Option 2 feels very tedious to have to set or unset an environment variable whenever I want to use gradle. Ideally I would like something like option 3 where I don't have to do any fiddling around whenever I change between personal or work projects. Is this possible? Or is there another solution that could solve my problem?

Comment: (Option 4: Don't do personal projects on your work laptop.)

Comment: It's actually my personal laptop, I have work projects on here for when I work from home